# Give a Yes/No option in a Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'd like to change the code below to present a yes or no option when a user clicks on 'X' but I'm afraid my java newbie skills don't stretch to it yet.  Any suggestions please?  I'd like to keep the code below as intact as possible in order to see what needs to be done differently for future reference.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WindowExit extends WindowAdapter
{
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Are you sure you want to close?" );
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use showConfirmDialog as follows:

```
int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to close?", "Close?",  JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
   System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: thanks to you all for the input, @Martijn, if amend the code as you suggest I get a yes or no option but the GUI closes whether I click yes or no!  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Eric: You should do this: `myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`

Answer (score 6):

Look at the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html). There is a `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION` which you can pass as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                    Object message,
                                    String title,
                                    int optionType)
```

With an `optionType` of `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION`